# I'm trying to upload a favicon to EE, but it says the .ico file type is not allowed

Tags: file-uploads

I am not a developer- but I want to upload my favicon to my EE site.  Which file folder (Content, Base Images, General Content, Gallery Images) should I upload it to?
Is this the proper way to upload the favicon?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about basic HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I would upload it to the root of the site and then link to it in the head of your document like this

```
<!--favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the file to the root of your site, as CreateSean said. To do this, you generally need to access your web server via FTP, File Transfer Protocol. I would recommend FileZilla for ease of use.

https://filezilla-project.org/

To log in to your web server via FTP, you'll need to know a username, password, and address (address is usually www.yourwebsite.com). You will probably need to contact your web hosting partner to get this information.

Once you have access, your web root is usually located here on a Linux server:

```
/var/www/html
```

I'm not sure where it would be on a Windows server. But this is generally where you'd upload your favicon.ico, and then you link to it as CreateSean said, with a link tag in your html header.